# Setting global environment variable in debian buster?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, debian, ubuntu-18.04

I need to set up an environment variable 'VERSION="x.x.x"' globally. So that I can read the same from python scripts, systemd services, and in any bash terminal. It should be permanent in any case even if the system is rebooted.

For the systemd service, I already put `EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment`.

From the searching, I set the variable in "/etc/environment"

```
VERSION="x.x.x"
```

and executed the command `source /etc/environment`

Now I can access it from python files, services, and from the shell.

I tried to add a new variable 'FILE_VERSION="x.x"' from the python file using the command `os.environ['FILE_VERSION']`="x.x"

But now the new variable is not accessible in any terminal nor in systemd services. `echo $FILE_VERSION` produces an empty string.

How can I add a variable to the/etc/environment from the python file which is run by the systemd service with User= pi?

Comment: `os.environ['FOO'] = "bar"` sets the env var only in the current python process. it cannot impact other processes. you need some inter-process communication to exchange info between processes.

Comment: what's the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Put the environment file in /etc/profile.d and ensure it has a .sh suffix

Comment: @pynexj I am running some python scripts using the systemd services. I need to save the version number of each scripts in an environment variable. so that i can access it by "echo ". It should be saved from the scripts itself to automate the version update when the file is modified.

Comment: @tomgalpin the environment file is `/etc/environment`. you want me to put the file in `/etc/profile.d`

Comment: Yes but environment.sh or create a new .sh file in /etc/profile.d